# Setting up primary keys in my tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few tables that are generated by different systems with no unique identifier available on the raw data.

Several files which are from the same system can be joined based on the:

```
interaction_time, customer_id, employee_id
```

Other files do not include the timestamp and there is only an `interaction_date`. The problem is that sometimes the same customer can speak to the same employee on the same day several times. So using `interaction_date, customer_id, employee_id` is not necessarily unique.

Using python (pandas), what I normally do is find all unique values of `interaction_date, customer_id, employee_id`. I filter these rows as a separate dataframe and do my joins. So this data is just the rows where one customer interacted with one employee one time on a certain date. Then I concat/append the rows which had multiple interactions back together with the post-joined data.

Any recommendations on how to set something like this up with SQL Server? I assume it must be fairly common. I am building tables right now and I am not sure what my primary key should be... a composite key of the date/customer_id/employee_id? How do I deal with the duplicates (these rows cannot be joined to other files because there is no clear way to tie the data together)?

**edit-** I just wanted to add that this is tying together the most granular data that we have. This would be used to tie back a survey (which might be received weeks later) back to a specific interaction, and to tie another file which has a length of that interaction, and another file which has whether a sale was made on that interaction, etc.

Comment: Will any other tables have a foreign key relationship to this one?

Comment: Definitely need an id for the interaction itself.  Then you'll want foreign keys for the employee and customer.  Seems like this should be an interactions table, therefore you shouldn't need names like `interaction_id` and `interaction_date`, `id` and `date` should be sufficient.

Comment: I have 7 separate files as my data sources. Some of those do not include timestamps. My issue is when there are multiple interactions on the same date. Say there are 2 orders in a day (no timestamp) for a customer with the same employee. There are 5 call records on that same day (with a timestamp). There is no way for me to know for sure how to match the 2 orders to a particular call. For sure, the orders took place during 2 of those calls, but I dont know which specific interaction had the orders. So it is tough to assign an interaction_id and know how it will relate on different files.

Comment: @LanceDacey, it sounds like you can only do guess work at this time.  You don't have the most atomic data to work with, so how can you go back and add it now?  Simply put, you can't.  You can only try to match the rows together loosely since there weren't established relationships between these files when they were written.  You can only work on how you can fix this for the future which is establishing a foreign key relationship between interactions and orders.

Comment: Understood. Yeah it is a shame because over 90% of the customers and employees only interact once on a date (which means you can easily join these rows together). A small subset, by chance, has a few interactions though. The other issue is that timestamps are not synced because the data comes from different systems from different companies so it is a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Since even `interaction_time, customer_id, employee_id` doesn't uniquely identify the values in your database, you can do two things:

1) Don't make a primary key at all (Though it is a bad practice)

2) Make a field call as `interaction_id` which will uniquely determine the interaction between consumer and employee. This field can be set to auto-increment.

Comment: My challenge with point 2 is for files which only have the interaction_date (no timestamp on the file), customer_id, employee_id. If there are 3 interactions (rows) for one employee/customer combination on that date, I can't imagine how I can join it to a file which might have 5 rows with the timestamp. So the customer and employee interacted 5 times (timestamps included), but another file without the timestamp only contains a subset of those interactions (3 out of the 5). There is no real way to be able to say which interactions tie back together with any certainty.

Comment: Why do you need those files which have interaction_date and not the timestamp? Once you have written them into database , you can query them on basis of just dates only as well .

Comment: True. The value of using them is that 90%+ of customers and employees only interact once on a given date. So I can tie back a value from a file with no timestamp to other files with the timestamp. A big one is an order. Since there was only one interaction between the customer and employee on a date, I know that the order was made during that interaction. This means that I know the timestamp, i know if there was a survey eventually, I know how long the interaction lasted, etc. It can be very valuable for analysis.

Comment: I think that you will be able to analyze the same thing even just with timestamp file.  Now since for one day, you will have only one record in this table, you can easily match the interaction with the table having interaction_time(technically it can be part of this table itself) and do the analysis.